# Select from table where values are coming from select2 with multiple selection

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have multiple select2, near to 10. So when user search using search form, I pass parameters for search. Now my problem is he can select all or he can select 2 only 1 or 2. So how I search from tables with this.

I can't search if one parameter returns empty it gives me empty sql result. I am doing this in yii2 but I need here only logic not exactly want in yii2. I will convert myself to yii2.

```
$employee=EmpDetails::find()->where([
'designation_id'=>$designation,
'process_id'=>$process,
'state'=>$state
 ])->asArray()->all();
```

Here `department`,`process`,`state` is array. It works fine if none of values are empty if one value is empty query returns null result.

Comment: pleas add some code man

Comment: post your research / efforts

Comment: use `OR` and `AND` condition to toggle between all your search criteria

Comment: i m sry i did not write anything.thats why i m asking.i need sql logic here.i tried but all i have written is wrong.

Comment: my problem is select2 are multi selection so every select2 can returns array of values.

Comment: i edited my question plz see if you understand

Comment: plz dont rate -1 if you not able to understand question then ask me here,for increasing you reps plz dont give negative to others.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my own answer for those who gave me -1 rep and did not understand the question.

```
$query=EmpDetails::find() 
->andFilterWhere(['city'=>$city])
->andFilterWhere(['state'=>$state])
->andFilterWhere(['department'=>$department])
->asArray()
->all();
```

This method `andFilterWhere` will remove empty query operands.
here `$city` and others are array